# What is the relationship among ';' / 'GO' / Transaction in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I understand well of T-SQL Transaction, begin trans, and eventually rollback or commit.

However, what is batch level? and what does these operators do? `';'` and `'GO'`

What is the relationship among the 3 terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GO` is not a T-SQL statement. `GO` is a batch separator used by SQL Server tools and utilities used to indicate the end of a block of statements in a script. When a `GO` is encountered in a script, the tools send the preceding block of statements as a single batch to SQL Server for execution.

A semicolon is the ANSI-standard statement terminator language element used to denote the end of a SQL statement. These terminators facilitate parsing. Although T-SQL allows semi-colons to be omitted in most cases, statement terminators are required when the following statement is a newer keyword, such as common-table expressions (introduced with `WITH`). Omitting terminators is deprecated nowadays and provided for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Ok. so the script will be splited into pieces (by 'go' and ';') and send to sql server run it one by one?

Comment: @Xin. Correct. SQL Server will see only the individual batches (without the `GO` terminator).

Comment: if `statement1; statement2; statement3 statement4 go statement5`, the server will exec [1+2+3+4] then [5]; or [1][2][3][4,5]? Thanks

Comment: @Xin, [1+2+3+4]  then [5] separately.

Answer (score 1):

; terminates a statement. GO terminates a batch of statements. ; is implied and isn't really needed unless running certain statements like MERGE where it's explicit usage is required.